# How can I Import excel file data(xls.xlsx) to Php/mysql.

Tags: php

I want to import excel file data(xls.xlsx) not csv to mysql using php.
Is there any possible way to import excel file and save it to temporary folder and get its data?..

Answer (score 0):

Found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/searbe/3284011) on GitHub, where a user has parsed a simple XLSX in PHP with SimpleXML and ZipArchive.

```
php
/**
 * I had to parse an XLSX spreadsheet (which should damn well have been a CSV!)
 * but the usual tools were hitting the memory limit pretty quick. I found that
 * manually parsing the XML worked pretty well. Note that this, most likely,
 * won't work if cells contain anything more than text or a number (so formulas,
 * graphs, etc ..., I don't know what'd happen).
 */
$inputFile = '/path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx';
$dir = '/path/to/tmp/dir';
// Unzip
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($inputFile);
$zip->extractTo($dir);
// Open up shared strings & the first worksheet
$strings = simplexml_load_file($dir . '/xl/sharedStrings.xml');
$sheet   = simplexml_load_file($dir . '/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml');
// Parse the rows
$xlrows = $sheet->sheetData->row;
foreach ($xlrows as $xlrow) {
    $arr = array();

    // In each row, grab it's value
    foreach ($xlrow->c as $cell) {
        $v = (string) $cell->v;

        // If it has a "t" (type?) of "s" (string?), use the value to look up string value
        if (isset($cell['t']) && $cell['t'] == 's') {
            $s  = array();
            $si = $strings->si[(int) $v];

            // Register & alias the default namespace or you'll get empty results in the xpath query
            $si->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main');
            // Cat together all of the 't' (text?) node values
            foreach($si->xpath('.//n:t') as $t) {
                $s[] = (string) $t;
            }
            $v = implode($s);
        }

        $arr[] = $v;
    }

    // Assuming the first row are headers, stick them in the headers array
    if (count($headers) == 0) {
        $headers = $arr;
    } else {
        // Combine the row with the headers - make sure we have the same column count
        $values = array_pad($arr, count($headers), '');
        $row    = array_combine($headers, $values);

        /**
         * Here, do whatever you like with the [header => value] assoc array in $row.
         * It might be useful just to run this script without any code here, to watch
         * memory usage simply iterating over your spreadsheet.
         */
    }
}
@unlink($dir);
@unlink($inputFile);
```